# Migration to play framework 2.6 brings java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.6

Tried to migrate to new play version 2.6.3 but after migration on start of the application I have exception like the following:

```
[DEBUG] p.s.a.i.n.u.i.PlatformDependent0 - jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.allocateUninitializedArray(int): unavailable
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at play.shaded.ahc.io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0$6.run(PlatformDependent0.java:290)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at play.shaded.ahc.io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0.<clinit>(PlatformDependent0.java:283)
        at play.shaded.ahc.io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent.getSystemClassLoader(PlatformDependent.java:637)
        at play.shaded.ahc.io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent.isAndroid0(PlatformDependent.java:661)
        at play.shaded.ahc.io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent.<clinit>(PlatformDependent.java:65
```

Will be really great to get some ideas how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you creating a manual instance of the WS client ? You should simply @Inject WSClient, and use that.

Comment: Because I need to configure it with some parameter

Comment: My suggestion would be not to use ws, but implement your own WSClient provider. That way, you can provide your own config, and if desired, make the config dependant on a @Named annotation.

If that's not an option, look at https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/JavaWS#directly-creating-wsclient that describes the proper way to manually create a WSClient.

Comment: Can you post a dependencyGraph of your project ? The error basically is a Netty bug, but seems to be present in 4.1. Since the shaded version uses 4.0, I'm surprised you get this.

Comment: We are running into the same issue and it is for sure related to our WSClient after the migration. I just wonder why we get an excpetion from netty as play 2.6 should use akka http instead?

Comment: Because WSClient still uses Netty, also in 2.6.

Comment: @stubbi as I understood new play should use aka http only for server side but for client it uses netty under the hood

Answer (score 0):

As per the link: https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/6855, upgrading netty version to 4.1.12.Final will fix this issue. I was also facing the similar issue got fixed after upgrading to 4.1.14.Final.